# VBA, For Each Loop, incrementing offset by 1 column

Tags: vba

I have a for each loop, how can I incrementally increase my cells output by one column? Currently this just writes to one cell in output.

```
Sub quarterly()

Dim result As String

rev = Sheets("fin").Range("B105:F105")

For Each x In rev:

    result = Replace(x, "M", "")
    Sheets("output").Cells(2, 2) = result

Next


End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a counter:

```
Sub quarterly()

dim j as long
j = 0

dim rev as range
rev = workSheets("fin").Range("B105:F105")

dim x as variant
For Each x In rev
    Dim result As String
    result = Replace(x, "M", "")
    Sheets("output").Cells(2, 2+j) = result
    j=j+1
Next


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

if your "target" range is empty then you could use `End(xlToLeft)` and step one cell right at any cell writing :

```
Sub quarterly()    
    Dim x, rev

    rev = Sheets("fin").Range("B105:F105").Value        
    With Sheets("output")
        For Each x In rev            
            .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1) = Replace(x, "M", "")
        Next
    End With    
End Sub
```