# How to offset in a "For each loop"

Tags: excel, vba

In a nested loop, I am trying to figure out how to indicate that the results should go in a different column for the second and third worksheets in the array. For the first worksheet in the array, everything is good. For the second and third worksheets, I need to place the result in the next column over. I'm just not sure WHERE to say that so that it doesn't mess up the "nested" part of the loop.

I was feeling pretty proud of myself for writing a nested loop until it didn't work. Finally, I realized that it was technically working, but that the loop was replacing the same cells of the same column over and over again because I didn't specify that the result should go over by one column. I found this [answer about offsetting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56380209/vba-for-each-loop-incrementing-offset-by-1-column) that looked promising but it is a little over my head.

```
Dim SG As Worksheet, SG2017 As Worksheet, SG2018 As Worksheet, SG2019 As Worksheet
    Set SG = Workbooks("Subgroup Summary Template").Sheets("SG")
    Set SG2017 = Workbooks("2017 Subgroup Summary").Sheets("2017")
    Set SG2018 = Workbooks("2018 Subgroup Summary").Sheets("2018")
    Set SG2019 = Workbooks("2019 Subgroup Summary").Sheets("2019")
Dim SGdata As Variant
Dim CurrentSGdata As Variant
    SGdata = Array(SG2017, SG2018, SG2019)
Dim i As Long

'ALL STUDENTS
For Each CurrentSGdata In SGdata
    With CurrentSGdata.Range("A1")
         For i = 3 To 8
         .AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=i
         .AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="Total Population"
         .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=school
                SG.Cells(i, 3) = CurrentSGdata.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas(2).Columns(15).Cells(1, 1)
                    On Error Resume Next
                SG.Cells(i, 6) = CurrentSGdata.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas(2).Columns(17).Cells(1, 1)
                    On Error Resume Next
            CurrentSGdata.AutoFilterMode = False
         Next i
Next CurrentSGdata
```

For example, how do I indicate that in the second iteration of `"CurrentSGdata,"` the `SG.Cells(i,3)` should become `SG.Cells(i,4)`?

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` is not needed more than once, and at that it should be used carefully and surgically.  The errors stay suppressed until the code tells it to turn back on.  Use `On Error GoTo 0` as soon as you are past the part that you want to ignore the error, so future problems that should be dealt with are highlighted.

Comment: As for your question - you can use a counter and increment it for each  `CurrentSGdata`  Eg start `n` at 3 then use `SG.Cells(i, n)`  Add 1 to `n` just before `Next CurrentSGdata`

Comment: Thanks for the note about  ```Error resume next```...I placed that in there because sometimes the code will only need to run for i=3 to 5, sometimes it will only run for i=6 to 8 and I didn't know how else to make it ignore the 1004 error and keep going.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example:

```
Dim i As Long, n As Long

'ALL STUDENTS
n = 3
For Each CurrentSGdata In SGdata
    With CurrentSGdata.Range("A1")
         For i = 3 To 8
             .AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=i
             .AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="Total Population"
             .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=school

             On Error Resume Next

             SG.Cells(i, n) = CurrentSGdata.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) _
                                .Areas(2).Columns(15).Cells(1, 1)

             SG.Cells(i, 6) = CurrentSGdata.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) _
                                .Areas(2).Columns(17).Cells(1, 1)

             On Error Goto 0 '<< stop ignoring errors

             CurrentSGdata.AutoFilterMode = False
         Next i
     End With 'missing in your code?
     n = n + 1
Next CurrentSGdata
```

Comment: Aha! I never considered the possibility of adding an n and then adjusting the n on the bottom. I knew it would end up being about where I placed the note, but could NOT figure it out.Thanks also for the edit about how to better use "Error Resume" and for pointing out that I was missing End with. I had that in there earlier today. I must have deleted it try to fix something else.